# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'main'

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to use the value of a click event in calculations.  Whenever I try to convert it to an int, it throws this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'main'
```

Here is a piece of the code that gets the error

```
def goto(self, event):
    self.ex = int(event.x)
    self.ey = int(event.y)
    self.find_distance(self.ex, self.ey)

def find_distance(xclick, yclick, self):
    #distance formula = sqrt((x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2)
    self.xadd = (xPos - xclick)^2
    self.yadd = (yPos - yclick)^2
    self.step2 = self.xadd + self.yadd
    print sqrt(step2)
```

Comment: The error isn't here. Post the stack trace.

Comment: Could you add ***all*** the code please?

Comment: what is `find_distance`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the `event.x` and `event.y` variables are 'corrupted' and not really integer values.  Try to `print(event.x)` or `print(event.y)`, that'll show you their true values.  I'm guessing `event.x` and `event.y` are instances of something.

You can also do `print(type(event.x))` and `print(type(event.y))`.  Thanks @Reut Sharabani.

Comment: You probably want to look at `type(event.x)`, **if** that is the error.

Comment: When I click anywhere, here is the output: `302 441 <type 'int'>`